# Should I be using Diff-in-diff? If not, then what should I use?

Tags: difference-in-difference

I'm looking at whether airlines entering into a merger has a positive or negative impact on profits. I have data for c.10 airlines who have merged and c.10 airlines that have not merged between the periods 2001 and 2015. Some of the data pre-merger is hard to get, but I will be able to find something, I am sure.

Essentially, I'm struggling to work out a model in which to analyse and then answer my hypothesis. I was thinking diff-in-diff, but due to the airlines not all merging at the same time, this confused me.

Someone mentioned setting up a Panel Regression, but again, I'm not sure if that is correct, or indeed how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your background? How sophisticated an analysis is this supposed to be?

Comment: Panel regression provides a setting to estimate difference-in-differences. So you're all right, in a sense. One way to do DID panel regression is to have one observation per airline per year, with random intercepts for airline and a continuous fixed effects for year and a term for pre-post merger and its product with time. If either the pre-post term or the product term are statistically significant, you would have some evidence of an effect.

Comment: If your idea is to test the probability of merging, it sounds to me like a logistic regression problem, where your Y (1 for merge, 0 otherwise) is dichotomous.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. I am an undergrad Economics student, so it is not supposed to be too sophisticated.

Comment: I don't think in this setting SUTVA, which is an assumption of this estimator, would be satisfied since airlines compete with each other.